# Jbutton invisible border with padding

Tags: java, swing

I have JButton that has an ImageIcon and some text.
I want to have transparent background with no borders but also want to have some padding.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Jbutton button = new JButton();

//Add image to the button
ImageIcon img= new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
button.setIcon(img);

//make button transparent
button.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));

//Remove border
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);

//add padding
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,10,5,50));
```

I still see gray border around by border.
When I do button.setBorder(null) that gray border line disappears but then I am not able to add padding.

If someone can please guide me on what I am doing wrong. I am very new to swing and have tried different answers but none of them have worked.

Thank you.

Comment: `button.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));` isn't how you make components transparent, instead, you need to set `setOpaque` and pass it false

Comment: I'd also have a look at [`JButton#setMargin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-) for adding padding

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried button.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10))  but did not work with border set as null. Is there anything else that i can try?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: Use `MatteBorder` instead of `EmptyBorder`. For example `button.setBorder(new MatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, color))`, where the color is the desired background.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0))`, Swing only supports fully opaque or fully transparent components, controlled via the `opaque` property, using a alpha based color can produce undesirable side effects
- Consider using `setMargins` to generate padding

Example...

[image: Screen Shot]

Original Image...

[image: Original Image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Launcher();
    }

    public Launcher() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JButton button = new JButton();

                    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Cup.png")));
                    button.setIcon(img);
                    button.setBorderPainted(false);
                    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    button.setFocusPainted(false);
                    button.setOpaque(true);
                    button.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    // Just testing to see there are glitches
                    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
                    frame.add(button);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Launcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I did find that if you used `setBorder`, it overrode the `margin` values

Answer (score 0):

How you set the margin, to any of swing component deoends on the layoutmanager.

If you are using GridBagLayout, you shall set insets on the GridBagConstraint object to the desired value.